# Plotly Scatter3D plot with consistent gradient

Tags: python, plot, plotly, scatter-plot

I'm trying to visualize temperature curves from different source in a 3D scatter plot. I have set `colorscale='Turbo'` so that hotter region will be read and colder region will be blue. But I cannot plot multiple scatter line with consistent color gradient. I understand the problem is occurring because I'm drawing multiple line separately. But I couldn't find a way to do it at a time. I can do it for `line` plots. But `line` cannot be drawn with gradient.

Here is the visualization.
[image]

For a curve negative temperature is shown as red.

My code:

```py
fig = go.Figure(go.Scatter3d(x=ch6_data['time'],  y=ch6_data['channel'], z=ch6_data['Ch6'], mode='markers', marker=dict(color=ch6_data['Ch6'], colorscale='Turbo', size=1, showscale=True)))

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter3d(x=ch1_data['time'],  y=ch1_data['channel'], z=ch1_data['Ch1'], mode='markers', marker=dict(color=ch1_data['Ch1'], colorscale='Turbo', size=1, showscale=True))
)
```

Is there any way to plot separate temperature curves with consistent gradient?

Comment: Can you provide sample data to reproduce the graph?